# validateaddress rpc error on daemon instance 0

Tags: node.js, port, daemon, p2p, host

I've set up a private vertcoin p2pool on ubuntu (had to swap from CentOS as I could not repeat some vital steps).

I save a picture of my vertcoind (default) daemon settings just in case this is important:

[image: vertcoind daemon getinfo]

Now using node.js stratum-pool https://www.npmjs.org/package/stratum-pool

I get this error:

```
error: [validateaddress rpc error on daemon instance 0 - {"type":"request error","message":"socket hang up"}] undefined
error: [Could not start pool, "not all addresses are valid"] undefined
```

the part of my code I am **not sure about** is this:

```
"ports": {                                          // Each pool can have as many ports for your miners to connect to as you wish. Each port can be configured to use its own pool difficulty and variable difficulty settings. varDiff is optional and will only be used for the ports you configure it for.
    "9174": {                                       // A port for your miners to connect to
        "diff": 32,                                 // the pool difficulty for this port
        "varDiff": {                                // Variable difficulty is a feature that will automatically adjust difficulty for individual miners based on their hashrate in order to lower networking overhead
            "minDiff": 8,                           // Minimum difficulty
            "maxDiff": 512,                         // Network difficulty will be used if it is lower than this
            "targetTime": 15,                       // Try to get 1 share per this many seconds
            "retargetTime": 90,                     // Check to see if we should retarget every this many seconds
            "variancePercent": 30                   // Allow time to very this % from target without retargeting
            }}},
"daemons": [{                                       // Main daemon instance// Recommended to have at least two daemon instances running in case one drops out-of-sync or offline. For redundancy, all instances will be polled for block/transaction updates and be used for submitting blocks. Creating a backup daemon involves spawning a daemon using the "-datadir=/backup" argument which creates a new daemon instance with it's own RPC config. For more info on this see: - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory & https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_bitcoind 
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5889,
    "user": "benzvertcoinwalletaddess",
    "password": "benzlongsecret"
    }],
"p2p": {                                            // This allows the pool to connect to the daemon as a node peer to recieve block updates. It may be the most efficient way to get block updates (faster than polling, less intensive than blocknotify script). However its still under development (not yet working).
    "enabled": false,
    "host": "-stratum+tcp://benzserver.private.com",
    "port": 9174,
    "magic": "0xfbc0b6dbL",                         // Magic value is different for main/testnet and for each coin. It is found in the daemon source code as the pchMessageStart variable. For example, litecoin mainnet magic: http://git.io/Bi8YFw & for litecoin testnet magic: http://git.io/NXBYJA
    "protocolVersion": 1300,                        // Found in src as the PROTOCOL_VERSION variable, for example: http://git.io/KjuCrw
    }
```

The above code is pulled directly from npm/github for stratum-pool (I have only indented my way to make it more readable for my own eyes and obviously I've attempted to put my details in).

My impression from reading the comments and researching around are that with this script you are **connecting to the daemon locally** (in this case a server) to get block/transaction updates and for submitting blocks **to stratum**.

Next the script is connecting to p2pool.. I think the comment is the wrong way round where it says 'This allows the pool to connect to the daemon'. Surely the script on my server connects to p2pool and tells it about the daemon on my server ***then p2pool can connect to the daemon as a node peer to receive block updates***!(Am I wrong?)

The part where it connects to p2pool I put the p2pool server3 port 9174 (for this I used the https://github.com/Lovok/p2pool-n version because server3 is not supported in p2pool-vtc).

The part where I specify the port of p2p I chose 5899 because if I look inside...

```
vi ~/.vertcoin/vertcoin.conf
```

You can see (Guide http://coingolem.com/how-to-setup-your-own-p2pool-node-144/) I wrote:

```
server=3


gen=0


rpcport=5899


rpcallowip=127.0.0.1


rpcuser=benzvertcoinwalletaddess


rpcpassword=benzlongsecret
```

The rpcport

Well I there is something I am not getting correct! Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
"daemons": [{                                       
"host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5899,// don't know where this originated from
    "user": "benzvertcoinwalletaddess",
    "password": "benzlongsecret"
    }],
"p2p": {                                            
    "enabled": false,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    //"port": defaults, //vertcoind --help
    "magic": "0xfbc0b6dbL",                         
    "protocolVersion": 1300,
    }
```

This is working!